# Cisco 800 Series how Access VLan ISP?

Tags: internet, cisco-commands

i have a ISP that provide Internet by Vlan and static Ip :

```
ip XXXXXXXX

netmask 255.255.255.248 (/29)

gateway YYYYYYYY
```

with microtick i can get it work, but with a Cisco 800 Series dont.
how can i get good configuration for it?

i try with

```
interface FastEthernet4

no shut

ip address XXXXXXXXX 255.255.255.0

ip nat outside

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 YYYYYYYY
```

but it doesnt work some advice?

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work*?  Can you ping the gateway address?  Also the subnet mask is different.

Comment: i receive internet by a media converter (optical fiber) with microtick when i plug rj45 all leds turn on, when i connect any other router or even a pc all still off in media converter, i have this cisco 800, i try the configuration but i can't ping gateway and lights in mediaconverter still off just like the cord was unpluggued

Comment: You have a cable problem.  Have you tried a crossover cable?

Comment: You also have a bad network mask. It seems your ISP is provided a `/29` network, but you are configuring a `/24` network. Also, if it is arriving via a VLAN, you are not configuring for that.

Comment: How did you get it to work on the MicroTik either, without using a sub-interface and defining a VLAN ID?